# SQLite Query in Android Application giving error

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey all one of my friend suggested me this (Tony), am I going wrong anywhere here ?
because this is giving runtime error. application stopped unexpectedly.
I may b wrong in syntax.
just help me out, thanks in advance. I am gratefull for your response.

```
public boolean checkData(String task1, String dte1, String startTime1)
{
```

SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
//SQLiteDatabase db = null; // get your database instance here.
qb.setTables("table1");
qb.appendWhere("task = ? AND dte = ?");

Cursor c = qb.query(this.db, new String[] { "task" }, startTime1+" BETWEEN stTime AND enTime",
        new String[] { task1, dte1}, null, null, null);

int a = c.getCount();
if(a>0)
{
    return true;
}
return false;

}

Comment: Posting the actual error message and stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Post to stack trace but just a quick guess stTime and enTime must be strings as far as startTime1 is string and should be quoted 'stTime' and 'enTime'

Answer (score 0):

HI ALL...
I solved this problem.
I was using string for BETWEEN clause, since upper limit and lower limit should be in numeric type. and so its working. But thanks for your help.